# load testing capabilities of load test tools

Tags: performance, testing, mocking, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a system that is due to undergo load testing.  Liaising with the load testing team has been difficult and less than helpful, but to cut a long story short they claim the load testing tool they will use cannot mock/simulate the functionality of the external dependencies of the system (a web service and a database).  As a result I am questioning their choice of tool.

In more detail, the system I have created receives a http request, after some processing it makes a call to a third party database (which we do not have control of) to retrieve more data, this then undergoes further processing, and finally a call is made to a client (which client is dependent on the data input).

So all-in-all we need to know how the server handles the load during the two processing stages, and the timing of the calls to the database and the final client.

My question is essentially this, can this be done with a load runner tool?
If so which tools can do this?
The load testers plan to use NeoLoad, and claim it is not possible, is this true?

Comment: Based on my understanding, the system receives a HTTP request and that is processed and a separate call goes to a 3rd party DB to retrieve some data.. This new data is now processed and sent back to the client.. Assuming all of the calls to/from the system are HTTP, there shouldn't be any problems in creating a script that can emulate this flow even with JMeter.. So unless there is some catch with the 3rd party DB, client or the web service, I do not see any issues with any tool being used here..

Answer (score 0):

We do load and resilience tests similar to you described with help of [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) load tool. This is very flexible tool based on scala language and allows to build different load scenarious. However it's required coding skills form the performance engineers.